# copy multiple text messages in WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, copy-paste

I am selecting multiple text messages in `WhatsApp` Conversation, and copying it.

But when I am trying to "`paste`", to forward it to other contacts,  it seems `WhatsApp` is adding the name (from whom that message is received in conversation) and time stamp associated with a message along with actual text of the message.

Is there a way to tell `WhatsApp` to only copy message content and exclude message sender and time stamp details?

**Device**: Micromax Canvas 4 and Android version : 4.2
`WhatsApp` App Version: 2.12.124

Answer (score 2):

This might be a workaround for what you are trying to do. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2142170

Just incase the link goes dead at some point, the link just says;

**Method:**

- Open the conversation to copy messages from in Whatsapp.
- Press menu button and select "More" then "Email conversation" then select "Without media" then select any of the Email applications shown, for example "Gmail" but don’t send any message just cancel.
- Open the Jota Text Editor application.
- Press menu button and select "File" and "Open" then select the "Whatsapp"  - folder, then "Media" folder, then ".Shared" folder. You will see the name of the conversation you asked to Email earlier. Open it.
- You will see all the messages of the conversation and you can copy multiple messages from here.

**Notes:**

We used "Jota Text Editor" application, but you can use any text editor or file explorer that can open a TXT file.
This method is for Android system, but can be used for other systems with minor modifications.
Use a file explorer to dispose accumulated TXT conversations in the ".Shared" folder. This folder is hidden but file explorers has an option to show hidden folders and files.

Hope this is works for ya.

Comment: to simply copy message Should I download an App? That sound too much of effort for fairly trivial task

Comment: True, but then you are at the mercy of the WhatsApp devs. Since they coded it to copy the name, timestamp and the message.